# Cropped layer in Kartograph.py for SVG maps

Tags: kartograph

I'm trying to draw a SVG map with two layers using [Kartograph.py](http://kartograph.org/docs/kartograph.py/).
The end result should be a single country on the first layer (say France) with the main rivers on a second layer.

The first layer with France borders works perfectly, but then I would like to add additional topological information on top of the map (say rivers). I have found the shapefile describing the rivers. However, when I add it in the JSON configuration file as shown below, the rivers are out of the country (but inside the square defined by the country, see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gobxd.png)).

The documention of Kartograph mentions `crop-to`, but I cannot get it to work. When I add this option to crop the second layer to the first one, all the river data does not appear.

```
{
    "proj": { 
        "id": "laea"
    },
    "layers": [
        {
            "id": "layer0",
            "src": "FRA_adm2.shp",
            "simplify": 2
        },
        {
            "id": "rivers",
            "src": "rivers.shp",
            "crop-to": "layer0", /* This is not working */
            "simplify": 0
        }
    ]
}
```